Issue with ssl cert on www to non-www redirection via https
I know this is asked about hundred times but I haven't managed to solve my issue with any result that came up.
So I'm trying to redirect all www requests to non-www along with https with DNS and apache2 vhost config.
my-example-domain.com => https://my-example-domain.com
www.my-example-domain.com => https://my-example-domain.com
http://my-example-domain.com => https://my-example-domain.com
http://www.my-example-domain.com => https://my-example-domain.com

All work except https://www.my-example-domain.com. My domain is on dnsmadeasy. I have the following records on there;
A record: my-example-domain.com => {serverIp}
HTTP redirection: www.my-example-domain.com => https://my-example-domain.com
vHost config (combined some answers I've found):
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName my-example-domain.com
     ServerAlias www.my-example-domain.com
     Redirect permanent / https://my-example-domain.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
     ServerName www.my-example-domain.com

     SSLEngine on
     SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-example-domain.com-0001/fullchain.pem
     SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-example-domain.com-0001/privkey.pem

     Redirect permanent / https://my-example-domain.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
     ServerName my-example-domain.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/my-example-domain.com

     SSLEngine on
     SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-example-domain.com-0001/fullchain.pem
     SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-example-domain.com-0001/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>

<Directory /var/www/my-example-domain.com/>
    Options +ExecCGI
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

The cert is via certbot/letsencrpt and it is for both www.my-example-domain.com and my-example-domain.com (sudo certbot certonly --dns-dnsmadeeasy --dns-dnsmadeeasy-credentials ~/.secrets/certbot/dnsmadeeasy.ini -d my-example-domain.com -d www.my-example-domain.com)
Now the issue is, when I try to visit https://www.my-example-domain.com, I get a SSL warning on all browsers as the certificate here is a wildcard dnsmadeeasy cert.

I did get in touch with them and they've sent me a rather confusing email with how they have a backend that handles the redirections and the only solution would be from their end is to install my certificate on their system. They've also said this;
It is most common within the industry to simply configure any URL redirections that you require on your own web application systems so that you may control SSL certificate management and other configuration parameters associated with your webserver. Our HTTP redirection records simply exist for the option to configure a URL redirection through your DNS provider.

How do I solve this? Would the first step be to remove the http redirection I've set up on dns made easy?

There is a "View Certificate" option in that browser warning you receive. Use it to check the certificate. The interesting part here is the last sentence in the first paragraph in the lower box inside that warning: "The certificate is only valid for *.dnsmadeeasy.com". That does not sound like that is your certificate you describe above.

Yeah that's the issue. Dns made easy applies their own cert before redirecting...

OK. So it looks like requests to https://www.my-example-domain.com are not actually served by your own virtual host (the one you defined in the question), but by some default host. Which obviously knows nothing about your certificate. Their response reads as if they did not really understand your actual situation. If I get it right your issue has absolutely nothing to do with that redirection. But with your own virtual host not using your certificate. Are you really sure you are actually allowed to configure arbitrary virtual hosts on their system?
